# How to check multiple values of a single column for each record in sql?

Tags: mysql

How to check multiple values of a single column for each record in sql?

My table appears like this,

```
ID   Date


----------


1   7/19/2016


----------


1   7/19/2016


----------


1   9/1/2016


----------


2   7/19/2016


----------


2   7/19/2016


----------


2   8/2/2016
```

I am looking for an output like this,

```
ID  Date


----------


1   7/19/2016


----------


1   9/1/2016


----------


2   7/19/2016


----------


2   8/2/2016
```

I am looking for result as [Total Id Count] = 4.
Am a tester and new to sql, please help me with this.

Comment: Have a look at the `DISTINCT` keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Distinct` to get distinct values or groups of values in a table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id, Date 
FROM MyTable
```

To see the latest orders grouped by date and customer, here's a full working example:

```
Declare @CustomerOrders table(CustomerId int, OrderDate DateTime, OrderId int)
Insert Into @CustomerOrders Values (1, '2016-01-01', 1)
Insert Into @CustomerOrders Values (1, '2016-01-01', 2)
Insert Into @CustomerOrders Values (2, '2016-01-01', 3)
Insert Into @CustomerOrders Values (1, '2016-01-02', 4)

Select * from @CustomerOrders

SELECT o.CustomerId, o.OrderDate, MaxOrder.MaxOrderId
FROM @CustomerOrders o inner join 
    (select o2.CustomerId, o2.OrderDate, max(OrderId) as MaxOrderId 
        From @CustomerOrders o2 
        Group By o2.CustomerId, o2.OrderDate) as MaxOrder 
    on MaxOrder.MaxOrderId = o.OrderId
```

Comment: Thanks,  but among the duplicate i have to take latest value, how to get that?

Comment: Thanks, yes but among the duplicate i have to take latest value , how to get that?There is a third column say "order", for duplicate values i.e. records where id and date are same i have to pick latest entry based on the field "Order" . Data type for Order is Integer.

Answer (score 0):

Below query for your updated question, this gives you the distinct count based on both id and date

```
SELECT COUNT (*) AS 'Total Id Count'
FROM ( 
       SELECT DISTINCT Id, Date 
       FROM <TABLENAME>
     )X
```

Comment: UPdated the answer, pls check

Comment: Did it give your desired result?

Comment: Thanks, yes but among the duplicate i have to take latest value, how to get that?

Comment: Thanks, yes but among the duplicate i have to take latest value , how to get that?There is a third column say "order", for duplicate values i.e. records where id and date are same i have to pick latest entry based on the field "Order" . Data type for Order is Integer.

Comment: You can use group by and Max to achieve that output, since i notice that already Jenson updated the query, i am not updating. I hope so far my query was useful.